# DECIMAL Index on CHAR column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am dealing with some legacy code that looks like this:

```
Declare @PolicyId int
;
Select top 1 @PolicyId = policyid from policytab
;
Select col002
From SOMETAB
Where (cast(Col001 as int) = @PolicyId)
;
```

The code is actually in a loop, but the problem is the same.  col001 is a `CHAR(10)`

Is there a way to specify an index on SOMETAB.Col001 that would speed up this code?

Are there other ways to speed up this code without modifying it?

The context of that question is that I am guessing that a simple index on col001 will not speed up the code because the select statement doing a cast on the column.

I am looking for a solution that does not involve changing this code because this technique was used on several tables and in several scripts for each table.

Once I determine that it is hopeless to speed up this code without changing it I have several options.  I am bringing that so this post can stay on the topic of speeding up the code without changing the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortcut to hopeless if you can not change the code, `(cast(Col001 as int) = @PolicyId)` is not SARGable.

Sargable

- [SARGable functions in SQL Server - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/)
- [SARGable expressions and performance - Daniel Hutmachier](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/01/19/sargable-expression-performance/)

After shortcut, avoid loops when possible and keep your search arguments SARGable.  Indexed persisted computed columns are an option if you must maintain the `char` column and must compare to an integer.

Comment: TIL:  SARGable.  Thank you.

Comment: Both Rex and SqlZim gave good answers, but I am giving the win to SqlZim because he pointed to some documentation explaining what functions can be run on a key column while still using the index.  This allowed me to give up on trying to do this without changing code.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the table structure, cast your parameter to the data type you are searching on in your select statement.
 `Cast(@PolicyId as char(10))` .  This is a code change, and a good place to start looking if you decide to change code based on sqlZim's answer.

Zim's advice is excellent, and searching on int will always be faster than char.  But, you may find this method an acceptable alternative to any schema changes.

Is policy stored as an int in `PolicyTab` and char in `SomeTab` for certain?

Comment: That is a good point, and a good way to try to work around the problem, but that requires changing the code. OP is "looking for a solution that does not involve changing this code".

Comment: You're right @SqlZim.  I edited a caveat to my answer that this is really for next steps.